# character array reads 3 inputs instead of 5 in c?

Tags: c, arrays, getchar, putchar

my code is given below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define size 5

void main(){

    int i;
    char letter[size];
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        letter[i]=getchar();
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        putchar(toupper(letter[i]));
}
```

and the output is :

```
bitto@HP-ProBook-4430s:~$ gcc test.c
bitto@HP-ProBook-4430s:~$ ./a.out
a
s
d
A
S
D
```

why is this happening? it was to read 5 characters and convert them to upper case.

Comment: poor neglected `'\n'`...

Comment: You need to read up a little on how terminals behave.  See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421860/capture-characters-from-standard-input-without-waiting-for-enter-to-be-pressed)

Comment: @EOF is certainly right. I expanded on your comment in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As EOF said, any input you have will be taking two chars as input because you are typing in <kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd> which `C` reads as `a` and `\n` so that is two chars, not one.

Comment: this explains it . typing in the characters without spaces  in the same line solves the problem.